# How to break sections (from react.app) down into React components?

Tags: reactjs

the code on App.js:

```
   <React.Fragment className="App">
      <Header title="Little Lemon" >
        <img src="http://jordanbr.pythonanywhere.com/static/restaurant/img/logo.png"></img>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <footer>
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Links To Social Media</p>
      </footer>
    </React.Fragment>
```

I would like to do the following:
Create a JavaScript file for each semantic element that will be a React component, for example, Header.js, Nav.js and Footer.js.
In each component, return the semantic HTML element.
In App.js, replace the semantic tags with the corresponding child components, for example <header></header> will be replaced with <Header/>.

I am new to react and am struggling to do this
Thanks in advance !

I tried creating a component on a different file (Header.js) and call it from App.js, but it didn't work.

Comment: Show us what you tried (Header.js) and explain what you mean with 'it didn't work'. Stack overflow works best if you don't ask people to write your code for you, but instead provide details on your attempt so we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to start:

https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy

https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react

https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-2-build-a-static-version-in-react

You can move the components shown in the above examples to separate javascript files. Try out the example above and it should give you a fair idea of component hierarchy.